# Making a simple HTTP request and read a reply

Tags: c, http, request

This has probably been answered before but with my current knowlage I can not find any answers that explains how this is done dispite a long time of searching so here it goes:

I have a sensor that sends it's information via a socket connected to a specific port. I know how to connect to a socket however the sensor changes port from each connection and the way to get the current port number is to make a HTTP request and read the port from the reply. All of the parameters for the sensor are also modified using HTTP so I need it for alot of things.

This is the specific command I need to run (taken from the documentation of the sensor):

```
Query: http://<sensor IP address>/cmd/request_handle_tcp?packet_type=B&watchdog=off&start_angle=0
Reply: {
"port":39731,
"handle":"s22",
"error_code":0,
"error_text":"success"
}
```

In python, this is simply done using the following code:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(f"http://{ip}/cmd/request_handle_tcp?packet_type=B&watchdog=off&start_angle=0").json()
handle = response["handle"]
port = response["port"]
```

But how is this done in C?

I hope this explains the question, the Python code is just if someone knows both Python and C, the question should hopefully be understandable even without the example python code.

Comment: Use a library like libcurl.

Comment: Yeah, libcurl is the way to go and it has lots of examples, see for instance https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html.

Comment: @kaylum I can use the curl command in a cmd prompt however when i create a c file i get the "curl/curl.h: No such file or directory" error. How do I link the curl library to my program? I can not find the curl library on my windows PC but the cmd prompt commands still works.

Comment: The C headers are not installed, or not found. Depending on the Linux distribution, you might be able to do something like `apt-get install libcurl-dev` or `dnf install libcurl-devel`. If it's an unusual or home-made Linux, you'll probably have to build libcurl from source.